# Output another word instead of the word in the table in a query

Tags: oracle

Suppose I have a table where I have a field which can have to values: "enabled" and "disabled".
Suppose want my query to output "unblocked" instead of "enabled" and "blocked" instead of "disabled". How to do that in Oracle?

Comment: Use `CASE WHEN ...`

Answer (score 0):

Either use the SQL standard way of `CASE WHEN ...` as ypercybe suggested in the comments or for more neat result, `DECODE` function:

```
DECODE(fieldref, 'enabled', 'unblocked', 'disabled', 'blocked')
```

Comment: I think DECODE is less readable. So I decided to use CASE - it seams more understandable for the person who will join the team to maintain this code. But anyway, thanks, it is very interesting to know about this possibility.